# Tracking users referral (PHP / MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

Greetings,

Is there any script that keep track users referral and set cookie on users referred so whenever they leave site and come back, it still will be count as referred by person..

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
//To set the cookie
if($refered)
 {
    setcookie('sitenameReferal', 'REFERER');
 }
//To retrieve it
if($_COOKIE['sitenameReferal'])
 {
    $referedBy = $_COOKIE['sitenameReferal'];
 }
```

It's simple enough.